# Setting NULL values to 0 for tables after geoprocessing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, lidar, las, null

I am trying to calculate LAS dataset statistics using the 'LAS dataset statistics' geoprocessing tool in ArcMap 10.3.1. I am working with LAS points and a shapefile of the plots and I need to extract the class wise statistics of the classified LAS

So far my methodology has been as follows:

1. I converted my LiDAR LAS file to LAS dataset separately for every class using the 'Create LAS Dataset' tool.
2. I have a shapefile of the plots according to which I want the plot wise statistics of the points to be generated. To do so, I used the 'LAS Dataset Statistics By Area' where I gave the class wise LAS data as 'Input LAS dataset' and the plot shapefile as the 'Input Polygon'.

However, as some of the plots do not have any points in them, the tool is failing to run and giving the 'ERROR: The field is not nullable [Z Min]'.

How do set the default settings of the resulting attribute table such that the table will have NULL values as 0?

Comment: Be vary that NULL value may have a different meaning than 0. Any python experience?

Comment: No. Just the basics. I just want to change the settings for the attribute table such that it does not stop executing the task even if it encounters a plot with no points in it.

Comment: I have also tried setting the default Z value as 0 in the 'Environments' but the same error keeps coming up.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll be able to bend the software to your will in this regard. Instead, you'll need to handle empty sources programmatically, avoiding data that doesn't meet input requirements.

Comment: @fatih_dur Do you have a solution via Python which will help me hard code these settings? I could give it a try.

Comment: I was planning to suggest a try/except block to omit this error, similar to the second example of [the tool's help page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/las-point-statistics-by-area.htm).